# What causes undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary

I have defined @categories in controller

```
#MoviesController
def new
    @movie = current_user.movies.build
    @categories = Category.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id] }
  end
```

and in new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @movie do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), prompt: "Select a Category") %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :director %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit to create new Movie I got an error undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

In console it's work fine...

Comment: If you have problem with `create` action, you should show `create` code. Backtrace would also be helpful. That said, I bet you don't set `@categories` in `create` and that's why it crashes when your record fails validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit the form, the navigator will make a new HTTP request (a `POST /movies`) that will lead you to the method create of your `MoviesController`. Then the error comes from that method. Double check your `create` method.

Also, we usually do something like this in create method :

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

  if @movie.save
    redirect_to '/somewhere'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

If it is the case for you, then it's possible that you `render :new` from the create method. The thing is that the `new.html.erb` view needs a `@categories` variable, which is not defined if you're coming from the `create` method. To fix that, just create the `@categories` variable within the `create`method :

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

  if @movie.save
    redirect_to '/somewhere'
  else
    @categories = Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    render :new
  end
end
```

Your question doesn't bring enough context, so I hope I spotted the right problem (which for sure is happening in movies#create method, not movies#new) ;)